# BlackBerry best practice to subscribe / unsubscribe users for pushes in BES infrastructure

Tags: blackberry, widget, push-notification

I'm developing application (widget) for BB OS v5-6 in BES infrastructure. 
That application will be available to install for the all users. 
What is the best practice to subscribe/unsubscribe users for the pushes in BES? Send push to the all users is not the best idea. And how do I know that user have installed application and running it?

Comment: Could you share what you're trying to achieve. Usually you do subscribe to pushes immediately as user recognised and unsubscribe if user really wants to stop updates (and allowed to do by design). You could make app "device startup autorun" and send any information about your app was installed

Comment: This is my plan:
1) User opens app and on load event app create request to the webservice to register user's PIN. Simple app="testapp" & PIN = "testPIN". The Server stores PINs in a table.
2) Server pushes messages only to the registered PINs which are in the table.
3) When user closes app the step 1 calls again webservice and server delete user's PIN from the table.
Is that approach correct?

Comment: Almost correct but why you should unsubscribe from push when application is closed?

Comment: Because server will sends the pushes. Network traffic will be affected I think, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Tkae a look on any messaging app. Even if user closes it he is receiving messages over push

Comment: What if user don't want to receive pushes anymore?

Comment: Add option to disable it